# ng-lightning with angular2+systemjs and NgModule

Tags: angular, ng-lightning

I tried to use ng-lightning (0.24.0) with angular2 (2.0.2) and systemjs module loader. The bundle loading is okay I think but when I try to call an ng-lightning template in an ngModule I've got template parse error. From a single component it is workink but inside an ngModule doesn't.

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/core": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/http": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/router": "~3.0.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.2",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.39",
"zone.js": "^0.6.25",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"@salesforce-ux/design-system": "^2.1.2",
"ng-lightning": "0.24.0",
"tether": "^1.2.4",
},
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }      from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NglModule }        from 'ng-lightning/ng-lightning'

import { AppRoutingModule }  from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent }     from './app.component';
import { TestModule }       from './test/test.module';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        NglModule.forRoot(),
        TestModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And in TestModule there is a test component and in the test component template theres the  template tag.

test.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }       from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }        from '@angular/forms';
import { TestComponent }      from './test.component';
import { TestRoutingModule }  from './test.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule, FormsModule, TestRoutingModule ],
    declarations: [ TestComponent ],
    exports:      [ ],
    providers:    [ ]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

test.component.ts

```
import { Component }    from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'testcomp',
    template: '<ngl-badge></ngl-badge>'
})
export class TestComponent {}
```

I've got this error:

```
zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'my-app' is not a known element:
1. If 'my-app' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-app' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<body>
<div class="slds">
    [ERROR ->]<my-app>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-center">
            <div class="slds-col">
"): TestComponent@21:4 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
```

is the main app component template. When I delete  tag from my test component template the app works fine. What is the problem? ng-lightning.umd.js loaded correctly as I see in network tab and no error after tsc compiling. So I don't understand.

Comment: Do you mean deleting\setting the `template : ''` tag it works fine ?

Comment: No, when I don't use <ngl> tag in the template, just other html tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Angular` is built with modularity in mind: this means that each Module should declare or import every component, directive and pipe that it wants to use.

For the parser to recognize a component, it *must* have been declared in the current module, or exported by another module that the current module imports. This is why -- for instance -- you had to import `FormsModule` in both of your modules in the OP.

Thus you get parsing errors when you try to use `ngl-badge` in `TestComponent` because you haven't told `Angular` that you intend to use `ngl-badge` when you created `TestModule`

Basically, just import what you need into `TestModule`

```
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule, FormsModule, 
                    TestRoutingModule, NglModule ],
    declarations: [ TestComponent ],
    exports:      [ ],
    providers:    [ ]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks. I try it with simple NglModule and didn't work, but you are right I think. Unfortunately there isn't NglModule.forChild() in ng-lightning. So maybe it's a mistake in ng-lightning?

Comment: @Dragi no problem. Which one worked? `NglModule.forChild()` or `NglModule`? I want to make sure that the answer has the correct import

Comment: NglModule is the  right form as the ngl document writes :)

Comment: @Dragi thanks I updated the answer. to use `NglModule`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is talking about `my-app`, that is not a known Angular component. Are you sure that you bootstrap the correct component in your tests and that it belongs in the declarations of one of your modules?

Also, I see that the selector of your `TestComponent` is `testcomp`, maybe this is the component you want to use.

Comment: I am sure, because when I use only simple html tags, my app working fine. This error come up when I write <ngl-...> tag in the template. So the error is not correct I think.

Comment: One more, I use angular2 routing so the route module bootstraps the TestComponent, and it works fine until I use <ngl-...> tags.